# Issue connecting python to Autocad

Tags: python, autocad

I'm currently working with `AutoCAD` in Python and recently attempted to establish a connection between Python and AutoCAD. I wrote a simple script to test the connection:

```py
from pyautocad import Autocad

def main():
    # Create an instance of AutoCAD
    acad = Autocad()

    # Check if there's an active document
    print(acad.doc.Name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

However, I encountered the following error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Architecture\create a line.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\Architecture\create a line.py", line 8, in main
    print(acad.doc.Name)
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 74, in doc
    return self.app.ActiveDocument
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 63, in app
    self._app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject('AutoCAD.Application', dynamic=True)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 178, in GetActiveObject
    clsid = GUID.from_progid(progid)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\engli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\.venv\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py", line 74, in from_progid
    _CLSIDFromProgID(str(progid), byref(inst))
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 1008, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

The error message `Invalid class string` suggests that the COM object for AutoCAD cannot be found or accessed. I'm unsure how to resolve this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/reclosedev/pyautocad/issues/19

Comment: Remove brace bracket `print acad.doc.Name`.

Comment: @GrzegorzŚwitek would like to know if you have the full version of AutoCAD or AutoCAD LT (they posted their comment as an answer that was deleted)

Comment: @toyotaSupra why? `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?`

Comment: @Codebling it’s on a full CAD license.